# How can I overwrite styles of an autofilled input when using Chakra UI?

Tags: css, google-chrome, emotion, chakra-ui

I'm styling my inputs inside [Chakra UI's extendTheme function](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme) however I'm struggling to style an input that has been autocompleted. Using the [`:autofill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill) pseudo selector doesn't seem to have any bearing because the browser (Chrome) has its own styles set with `!important` which forces the input's background colour to be white.

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: {
         field: {
            bg: "gray.700",
            color: "gray.300",
            _hover: {
              bg: "gray.500",
            },
            _focus: {
              bg: "gray.500",
            },
            // This does not work
            _autofill: {
              bg: "gray.500",
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Just incase anyone has the same issue, I couldn't figure out how to override the default browser `background-color`,  so instead I gave it a `box-shadow` value that creates a similar effect. Box-shadow is not set by the browser's autofill styles so this works well for my case.

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: {
         field: {
            bg: "gray.700",
            color: "gray.300",
            _hover: {
              bg: "gray.500",
            },
            _focus: {
              bg: "gray.500",
            },
            _autofill: {
              border: "1px solid transparent",
              textFillColor: "#c6c6c6",
              boxShadow: "0 0 0px 1000px #232323 inset",
              transition: "background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s",
            },
         }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow, supercrazy. Thanks for the hack. Has somebody bothered reporting this to the Chakra UI team yet? This should definitely find some mention in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As [TommyR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70991757/4212153) explains, this is currently broken in Chakra UI.

However, this does work in variants.

A somewhat clean fix would be to create a variant for this, and set it as a defaultProp:

```js
Input: {
  variants: {
    backgroundFix: {
      field: {
        bg: "green.500",
      },
    },
  },
  defaultProps: {
    variant: "backgroundFix",
  },
},
```

If wanted, you could extend other existing variants, like so:

```js
Input: {
  variants: {
    outlineBackgroundFix: (props) => ({
      field: {
        ...defaultTheme.components.Input.variants.outline(props).field,
        bg: props.colorMode === "light" ? "white" : "gray.800",
      },
    }),
  },
  defaultProps: {
    variant: "outlineBackgroundFix",
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the reason that Input background styles are not applied via `baseStyles` is that styles for variants override `baseStyles`, and each variant sets background (often to 'transparent'). As such, I don't think this is a bug, and is alluded to in a callout in the docs:

> Pro tip : If you're looking for a list of parts of a multipart component you can check it by clicking on the "View theme source" button at the top of the documentation page for that certain component. 
> https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#styling-multipart-components

To override the variant's default theme, you can define just the parts you want to change, which will be merged with the default styles for the variant.

Check the source for Input: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/%40chakra-ui/react%402.4.2/packages/components/theme/src/components/input.ts#L115

HT to previous answers for pointing the way!

```js
const variantFilled = {
  field: {
    bg: "red.500", // merged with the default styles for `filled`

    /* // default styles:

    border: "2px solid",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    bg: mode("gray.100", "whiteAlpha.50")(props),
    _hover: {
      bg: mode("gray.200", "whiteAlpha.100")(props),
    },
    _readOnly: {
      boxShadow: "none !important",
      userSelect: "all",
    },
    _invalid: {
      borderColor: getColor(theme, ec),
    },
    _focusVisible: {
      bg: "transparent",
      borderColor: getColor(theme, fc),
    },
    */
  },
  addon: {
    /*  
    border: "2px solid",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    bg: mode("gray.100", "whiteAlpha.50")(props),
    */
  },
};

export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      variants: { filled: variantFilled },
    },
  },
});
```

If you need access to props to toggle mode:

Docs: [Component Style > Styling multipart components](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#styling-multipart-components)

```js
import { inputAnatomy } from "@chakra-ui/anatomy";
import { createMultiStyleConfigHelpers, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { mode } from "@chakra-ui/theme-tools"

const { definePartsStyle } = createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(inputAnatomy.keys);

const variantFilled = definePartsStyle((props) => ({
  field: {
    bg: mode("gray.100", "whiteAlpha.50")(props),
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    const theme = extendTheme({
      components: {
        Input: {
          baseStyle: {
             field: {
                bg: "gray.700",
                color: "gray.300",
                _hover: {
                  bg: "gray.500",
                },
                _focus: {
                  bg: "gray.500",
                },
                // This should work
                _autofill: {
                  transition: 'background-color 0s 600000s, color 0s 600000s',
                }
             }
          }
        }
      }
    })
```